# How to disable a constraint programmatically?

Tags: swift, constraints

How to disable a constraint programmatically?

I have two constraints, that the priority of one depends for the other. As far as I know the constraints priority can’t change programmatically when they are installed (it throw me an error), So the idea is, when X occurs the constraint A is disable and the constraint B is enable, and when Y occur A is enable and B disable

```
IBOutlet weak var constraint_A
IBOutlet weak var constraint_B

... 

func configureViews() {
   if x {
        constraint_A.disable = true
        constraint_B.disable = false
   }  else {
        constraint_A.disable = false
        constraint_B.disable = true
   }
}
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constraints have a boolean property called `active` so if you want to disable a constraint you can easily call it:

```
constraint_A.active = false
```

Comment: But be warned. This doesn't just disable the constraint. It removes it. If there is no persistent reference to it, the constraint will then be destroyed. So if you are thinking of using this constraint later, capture it before you disable it. _A weak reference will not be sufficient for this._

Comment: @matt So what do you suggest to use in order to capture the constraint? and, Is this approach a good approach to select which one should have more priority than the other one?

Comment: Swapping constraints in and out is a _great_ idea. I do it all the time. But, as I already told you, if you mark your IBOutlet as `weak` you will lose the constraint entirely as soon as you disable it.